# Can I force MySQL to use an index?

Tags: mysql

I created a table which has close to 800,000 records.

```
mysql> describe automation_search_test;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| filename | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| site     | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| script   | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| station  | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| result   | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| failcode | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| stbmodel | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| rid      | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| testdate | text    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

with an index on the `filename` column

```
mysql> show index from automation_search_test;
+------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                  | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| automation_search_test |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | id          | A         |      767825 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| automation_search_test |          1 | ast_fname_idx |            1 | filename    | A         |      767825 |      255 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

With a WHERE condition, a query against the `filename` column uses the index without problem.

However, a simple SELECT query against the `filename` column ignores the index

```
mysql>  explain select filename from automation_search_test;
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | automation_search_test | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 767825 |       | 
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

How can I force the use of this index??

Comment: What do you want it to use the index for?  For ordering the results?  If so, you can add an ORDER BY clause.  Or are you wanting MySQL to retrieve the data from the index rather than the table?

Comment: @Mark: the index rather than the table.

Comment: Where is the original query? And better show `show create table` rather than `describe`

Comment: `mysql> show create table automation_search_test;
CREATE TABLE automation_search_test (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  filename text,
  site text,
  script text,
  station text,
  result text,
  failcode text,
  stbmodel text,
  rid text,
  testdate text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY ast_fname_idx (filename(255))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=767826 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1 `

Comment: @Chris:  I believe the term for that is a "covering index".  The question makes more sense to me now, though.  I was a bit puzzled at first.

Comment: @Chris: give the result of `show create table` and show us the original query

Comment: @Chris: you can put it in the question itself. And put there your query too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you are looking for a covering index.  A covering index (one that can satisfy the entire query without going to the table) only works if it contains the complete data.  In your example, the index on `filename` includes up to 255 characters.  If the actual file name were longer, it would not contain the entire data, so it is not a covering index for that query.

If `filename` had a type such as `varchar(255)`, then it would use the index for the example query.

Comment: Part of the problem is that we're having to store (up to 255 characters) long filenames. We need to rethink storage...and database design.

Comment: @Chris:  Out of curiosity, I played with it a bit but could not convince MySQL to use the index even if I used a query where, in theory, it could.  For example, "select substring(filename,255)..." could use that index, but according to "explain" it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Since `SELECT` without a `WHERE` condition returns all of the values in that column, there is nothing for the index to do.

That's a bit like asking why the index at the back of a textbook isn't used when I want to read the whole book.