# mysql query takes 145 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I have a a mysql db with myisam engine. Along with many other table I have this table "et" which has around 8137037 records.

I have created indexes (individual index of column hname and pnum, it did not help much later created joint index of hname and pnum and it help execute within a second)such that queries as follows

```
 select st from et where hname='name' and pnum='1' limit 1
```

execute fast (with in a second) but the problem is I must execute this query

```
select st from et where hname='name' and pnum='1' order by id limit 1
```

where id is the primary key of the table and this query sometimes take 145 seconds :(

how can i resolve this issue?

#### table structure

```
mysql> describe et;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| down_id    | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| port_index | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date1      | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| username   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hname      | varchar(80) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pnum       | varchar(10) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status     | int(3)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| department | int(2)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| comments   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| issue      | int(1)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

#### Indexes

```
mysql> show indexes from et;
+-----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
|Table| Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| et  |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | id          | A         |     8137037 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | status         |            1 | status      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | down_id        |            1 | down_id     | A         |     4068518 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | issue_idx      |            1 | issue       | A         |     8137037 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | hname_idx      |            1 | hname       | A         |         283 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | pname_idx      |            1 | pnum        | A         |         136 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | clientid_idx   |            1 | client_id   | A         |     8137037 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | date1_idx      |            1 | date1       | A         |     8137037 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | department_idx |            1 | department  | A         |     2712345 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | hp_idx         |            1 | hname       | A         |         283 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| et  |          1 | hp_idx         |            2 | pnum        | A         |        4834 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

#### Explain Plan

```
mysql> explain select status from et where hname='mmah' and port_num='1' limit 1;
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                    | key          | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | error_trap | ref  | hname_idx,pname_idx,hostport_idx | hostport_idx | 96      | const,const |   37 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> explain select status from et where host_name='mmah' and pnum='1' order by id desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                    | key          | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | error_trap | ref  | hname_idx,pname_idx,hostport_idx | hostport_idx | 96      | const,const |   37 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *(reference)* [Optimizing Queries with `EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355220/can-i-force-mysql-to-use-an-index) for a hint on how to lay out database questions.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating an index of (id, hname,pnum)?

If your index includes and is already ordered by ID then that effectively removes that concern.

There is no reason you cannot include ID in another index, just because it is also the primary.

Comment: Further more have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

"In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause without doing any extra sorting."

Comment: i am not sure but is it worth creating and index of these 3 together because since id is primary key and has exactly the same number of different values as the number of rows in the table which is equal to 8137037 and growing

Comment: I would certainly expect it to be worth it, it might be worth giving it a go, it will take make a minute or two to create the index?

Edit: Also see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/ for more information on optimising sorting of results sets
You could create it, do an explain and see the results, then if its no good, drop the index.

Comment: And further more http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Using B-Tree indexes to pre-order your results set is well documented.

Comment: Unfortunately creating and removing index is a nightmare here it take around 22 minutes to do that.

Comment: It might be a necessary evil I'm afraid, clearly having to sort all the rows is the issue here (I'd expect your explain to say its hitting a temp table in the process).  You need to optimise out the sorting operation and the only way to do that is to include the fields into your index such that the index is already ordered.

Comment: I agree that an index on (hname,pnum) will probably be a good idea.

Comment: An index on just hname and pnum won't help in this situation, infact in the original question he states he has already done this, the issue is ordering the results and then doing the limit, mysql will only use 1 index so the fact ID is a primary key is irrelevant.  This type of operation NEEDS an index which will include both the 2 fields being selected upon but also the order by field.  The several links I posted above should explain this.

Comment: Guys do you mean i should create a joint index of (id,hname,pnum) or (hname,pnum,id). Are these same i dont think.

Comment: They are not the same, I think it'll be (hname,pnum,id) off the top of my head.

Comment: @ashryalls I have started to create the index lets see.

Comment: Thanks everyone creating a joint index of hname,pnum,id helped now results are returned within a second.

+--------+
| status |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Comment: Glad to have been helpful, if you can accept this answer it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index in the table that contains hname and pnum.

This will cause MYSQL to create a shadow table, which only contains those 2 parameters, and whenever those 2 parmaters are used in a where, it looks in that shadow table, and finds them very fast.